# javascript addlistener not working

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to simply get alert('yay') to show up when I click a button. Before I changed playbtn.addEventListener.playPause() to playbtn.addEventListener.playPause, it ran immediately, now it won't run at all.

I want it to run when I click. Here is the code I'm using.

```
    function initAudioPlayer(){
    var audio, playbtn;
    audio = new Audio();
    audio.src = "http://livefromthestruggle.com/musiccontent/Contact%20Me%20For%20Purchasing%20Options%202.wav";
    audio.loop = false;
    // Set object references
    playbtn = document.getElementsByTagName('button');

    // Add Event Handling
    playbtn.addEventListener("click", playPause);
    // Functions
    function playPause(){
            alert('yay');
        //if(audio.paused){

           // audio.play();

       // } else {
    //      audio.pause();
       // }
    }

}
window.addEventListener("load", initAudioPlayer);
```

Comment: `playbtn = document.getElementsByTagName('button')[0];`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `document.getElementsByTagName` to `document.querySelector` and ideally, give your button a useful class.

```
<button class="Audio-play">play</button>

var audioPlay = document.querySelector(".Audio-play");
audioPlay.addEventListener("click", playPause);
```

The reason it's not working is because you're asking for an HTMLNodeList of ***ALL*** `<button>` elements on the page.
Even if it's a list of 1.

The list doesn't have `.addEventListener` on it.
So either you can grab a list of all buttons, and hope you know which one it is in the list

```
allButtons[35].addEventListener("click", toggleMusic); // listen on the 36th button found
```

or you can use querySelector and classes/IDs/etc to find the first instance of a more specific identifier.

Comment: when I do this on Fiddle...
 btns = document.getElementsByClassName('button');
 btns[1].addEventListener("click", playPause);
It works. Why isn't it working on my website? There are 3 buttons of the class "button" (last song, play, next song) and it doesn't work even though it works perfect 100% on fiddle.

Comment: @MartezMcKinzie the code you posted is this: `playbtn = document.getElementsByTagName('button');` In that code, `playbtn` isn't a button, it's a ***list of buttons***.  When you write `playbtn = document.getElementsByTagName('button')[1]` it works, because you're selecting the second element from the list of buttons.